# How to unlock Blitz Play

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I cannot seem to unlock Blitz Play. I have completed all the side missions except for one Rampage. Do I have to complete all the Rampages with Trevor?

Answer (score 2):

To unlock [Blitz Play](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Blitz_Play), you need to complete:

- Preparation Missions

  - [Trash Truck](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Trash_Truck)
  - [Tow Truck](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Tow_Truck_(mission))
  - [Boiler Suits](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Boiler_Suits)
  - [Masks](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Masks)
- Story Missions:

  - [By The Book](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/By_The_Book)
  - [Did Somebody Say Yoga](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Did_Somebody_Say_Yoga%3F)
  - [Hood Safari](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Hood_Safari)
  - [The Merryweather Heist](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Merryweather_Heist)
- Assassination Missions

  - [The Hotel Assassination](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hotel_Assassination)